# How is spell resistance calculated for the Divine Soul feature of the Contemplative prestige class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, prestige-class, character-levels, spell-resistance

How is spell resistance calculated for the Divine Soul feature of the Contemplative prestige class?

In the Contemplative's Class Features description (page 32, *Complete Divine*), it is written:

> **Divine Soul (Su):** At 7th level, a contemplative gains spell resistance. Her spell resistance equals her class level + 15. In order to affect the contemplative with a spell, a spellcaster must roll the contemplative’s spell resistance or higher on 1d20 + the spellcaster’s level.

My question is about the classes involved in calculating spell resistance.

For example, does a Cleric 10, Contemplative 10 have spell resistance 35, or 25?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 25

"Her class level" in this case refers to "levels in the contemplative class". So a 10th level cleric, 10th level contemplative has 10+15 = 25 spell resistance.

If it had been the character's level instead of levels in the contemplative class, it would have called it out as "the  contemplative's total level" or "the  contemplative's level", instead of "her class level", which refers specifically to levels in the  contemplative class.